# Generate auto call for a PHP file and email daily, weekly and monthly

Tags: php, scheduled-tasks

I have a report.php file where i have written a sql query, where it saves a .csv file in the browser when i execute the report.php. i want that report.php file to execute automitacally and send .csv file to the predefined emails. every day, every week and every month.
Is there any simple way to do it...

Answer (score 1):

Use a cron job to execute the file then use the options

```
* * * * * * \path_to_report.php
```

Inside report.php include a function to send emails to a list in the database.. You can use the php pear package..http://pear.php.net/package/Mail